# Consecutive numbering skiping empty cells with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to auto-number only the existing names on a cell using an arrayformula:

I have two cells one for the **names** and the other for consecutive **numbers**.

Here I have an example of what I want to achieve:

[Link to My Google Sheets Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14foaxwy0-Yw47VQk_Eplvo9L7vtTwEXCAsI3QaHI7vE/edit?usp=sharing)

The current formula still counting the empty spaces, but it only should count the ones with content:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISBLANK(A2:A12),"",row(Z1:Z12)))
```

**Here is an ScreenShot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MATCH(A2:A12&ROW(A2:A12),FILTER(A2:A12&ROW(A2:A12),A2:A12<>""),0)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it worked like a charm. I don't understand very good the formula, but it do the job! thank you!